# Are there other ways to earn reputation other than answering and asking questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, answers

Are there other ways to earn reputation other than answering and asking questions? I know you can get badges for other things, but are there other ways to get reputation?

Comment: Well... You can get 100 points for associating an account from another site, but you've gotta already have rep on *that* account.

Comment: Did you miss this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37096/who-or-what-is-this-so-user ?

Comment: @random He technically _did_ answer questions...

Answer (score 7):

You can now bubble up your [reputation through suggested editing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/):

- **+2** - Tag wiki excerpts
- **+2** - [Tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83936/tag-wiki-edit-titles-dont-show-up-in-the-reputation-drop-down)
- **+2** - [On a post as a sub 2000 reputation user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep)

You can only tick a maximum of **+1000** through suggested edits. If you're over 2000 you don't earn the +2 kicker on a post edit.

Answer (score 3):

Association for 100, Accepting Answers for 2, [Alien Methods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37096/who-or-what-is-this-so-user/37100#37100) for hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

Besides associating your accounts, no. That's all people do here. (Rep for comments/editing answers doesn't strike me as the best idea)

Comment: It's what they do. It's all they do. And they absolutely will not stop, ever, until they hit their rep cap!