# Edit a question (from other user) and get +2 rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits, suggested-edits

There was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872314/overloading-fork) Question on SO this morning (GMT Time). I made an edit (I don't have enough rep to do it without peer review) and the changes I commited were

1. Change the Title
2. Fix code Indent

After this happened, my changes were accepted, and I `+1`-ed the question and put it as a favorite.

Within 1 minute I got `+2` reputation, I have done peer-review-ed editing at least twice before but nothing like that happened.

Is this a bug on the system or is it standard behaviour? Is there any link we can find the detailed behaviour of how the edit-system works? Do all edits (either peer-reviewed or not) give you some reputation ?

Thanks for your time. I hope question is inline with the rules.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This just got implemented:

[image: FYI ... edit suggestions queue is now visible to all 10k rep users... they also get the link at the top of the page. Also... when an edit suggestion is approved... a 2 point rep bonus is given to the suggestor... daily cap and total 1000 rep cap for this applies]

So nope, it's a feature not a bug!

Comment: Wouldn't this introduce more sock-puppeteers now ? It's relatively easy(-ier) to get 15 reputation that way now, without even having to do a question or an answer (hence not having to deal with downvoting). Is there a required rep level to do even peer-reviewed edits?

Comment: @Muggen A (rather unfortunate, imho) effect of reputation for proposed edits is that edits now must be "substantial enough" to get into the queue. See a great post with a "youre" in it? You can't fix it.

Comment: 500 accepted edits, required to get 1000 rep, would mean you'd have to edit a post on nearly 1% of all the questions on Super User. Surely gaming would require more effort than it's worth

Comment: @Bruno, nice edit. Note that the `title` text can also be added after the link, like `[1]: http://i.imgur.com/SNrTW.png "Title text here"` (as opposed to the `alt` text, in `![enter image description here][1]`).

Comment: @Arjan I wasn't sure how to do that so I added the tag. Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 14):

You can get a maximum of +1000 rep from edit suggestions.

Each approved edit suggestion increases your reputation by +2.

(There are [other rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work), such as, a given user can only approve so many edits by another user in a day, etc, but these are the important ones.)

Comment: Why would you want to limit the rep. Someone who does 500+ edits surely has great interest in improving SE, so why limit the rewards?

Comment: You could always allow `+2` rep for the first 500 edits, and then just allow further edits without any +rep gain.

Comment: @Tshepang Well, by the time you get 1000 reps from edits you're about half way to being able to edit 'normally' anyway, so it's not really that important a restriction anyway.

Comment: @mug The limit only applies to +2 rep increments, not how how many edit suggestions you can make.

Comment: @yij I guess 2k editing should have honored with their 'normal' edits anyways. Why not?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood i asked a [similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81163/154790) and was wondering.. why don't we make it for normal edits too..

Answer (score 2):

[The +2 bonus for edit suggestion has been added tonight.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/488663#488663) Enjoy!