# Where did this Reputation come from?

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit a question (from other user) and get +2 rep ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep)

My reputation just jumped 2 points for no visible reason.  The graph shows it being because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878908/parallel-foreach-behaving-like-a-regular-for-each-towards-the-end-of-the-iteratio), but I never answered it, just submitted a small revision.

I've never seen anything on Meta, or S.O. that suggests that Edits earn you rep.  What happened?

Comment: Edited FAQ 'How does reputation work' to include this method of gaining rep.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're under 2,000 reputation, you get 2 points (with [a maximum of 1,000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep/77508#77508)) for every approved edit you suggested.

Comment: Up to a maximum of 1,000 points.

Comment: Where is that documented?  I got pretty confused.

Comment: @Cpfohl it's documented unofficially here (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep). It only just got implemented so I'm guessing it might not have made its way to official pages yet.

Comment: Thanks! It's now officially (by me...you should go check accuracy) part of the "How does reputation work" community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

You get reputation if you have an edit suggestion approved.