# It seems I have gained 2 points reputation for an upvote

Tags: support, reputation, answers, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit a question (from other user) and get +2 rep ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep)

[I'm confused about Polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907417/im-confused-about-polymorphism)

In the above question I upvoted the currently top voted answer. When I upvoted it it changed from 2 to 3. Now it has 6 votes.

My Recent Activity area (click the envelope on the top) shows that I have gained 5 reputation for an upvoted question and 2 reputation for one thing on the question above which is probably the upvote I gave since that is the only thing I did. It also shows the total of seven on the reputation tab.

How is this calculated that I get 2 reputation for an upvote? It never happened before.

Answer (score 5):

You received two points for your accepted edit to the question.  See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep) on Meta.