# Getting two reputation points for a suggested edit even after reaching the 1000 reputation points boundary

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, suggested-edits

Look at [this answer by Jeff Atwood ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep/77508#77508). It means any Stack Overflow user can earn a maximum of 1000 reputation points from suggested edits. I have already earned 1000 reputation points by suggesting edits. Look at this picture:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/maFPN.png]

But still I am getting two reputation points for suggested edits (and that's where I suspect a bug), which will be removed one day later (that is fine). Look at this picture:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pr3V.png]

So is it a bug or not?

#### EDIT

When I post an answer and delete that answer, at that time my reputation is recalculated and the actual reputation is shown (after removing the suggested edits' +2 reputation). This happened thrice.

And now I can not tell more about this issue. See [my reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1369235/hims056?tab=reputation).

Comment: Wild guessing time! I predict that a post you had suggested an edit on got deleted, causing you to lose the 2 reputation from it (those don't show up in your history). I also predict that the system doesn't actually trigger a recalculation of your previous edits which you *didn't* get reputation for due to the suggested edits cap and just gives you a +2 on the next one. Just wild guesses though. Try finding another post to edit and see if it gives you another +2.

Comment: Sideway question: Where is the first screenshot from ? Please let me know.

Comment: @mtk: [/reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation)

Comment: Cool, Thanks for that !!!

Comment: @animuson look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856328/mysql-invisible-process).
Yesterday I earned +2 rep(that is not fine as I have already earned 1000 rep. from suggested edit). and today that rep. was removed(that is fine).

Comment: Well, if it's self-fixing then I don't see much of an issue with it.

Comment: That is fine but my question is `Why do we get +2 rep. on suggested edits even after already earned 1000 rep. from it?`

Comment: How on earth do you have 1000 reputation from suggested edits?

Comment: When showing a screenshot from your reputation page, avoid showing the −1 parts: Those are only visible to you, and they show which posts you down-voted. It doesn't say if you down-voted the question, or one of the answers, but it's rather preferable avoiding any vindication.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I have updated both pictures.

Comment: @hims056: You are the best editor I have ever seen. Your profile is full with suggested edits reps.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Don't know whether it *Taunt* or *Praise*.

Comment: @hims056: Why it would be Taunt? Why do you feel that?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk that's correct. I am still editing the post. And will continue...

Comment: @kiamlaluno I thought that the -1 was for Answers only; down-voting a Question results in 0 rep change, no?

Comment: @Gaffi That is correct. The −1 doesn't say which answer has been down-voted, but in the case there is just an answer, it is easy to know who has been down-voted. `:)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's bug-*like* (although not really a bug since you end up with the correct amount of rep), but I don't think many people see this. At 2000 rep, you can directly edit questions and answers, and so you don't get the +2's for suggesting edits anymore. The cap is at 1000 points of rep from edits. So the only people who see this will be folks with rep between 1000 and 2000 who edit like mad, but get very few points from asking or answering questions. In practice, I doubt that this comes up very often.

I have 45K and have made a boatload of edits in my day, but `/reputation` says I only got 18 reputation from suggested edits; looks like I hit 2000 points on my eleventh day on SO. I missed seeing this issue by a *mile*! I expect this is fairly typical -- it seems hard to imagine somebody making 500 edits before they get 1000 points of rep from some other source.

Comment: So I will never face this little issue from now!