# Lost reputation on edits (posts are NOT deleted)

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits

I have reached my reputation cap (was at 245) for today with both edits and answers but kept editing and answering.

Suddenly the reputation for all the edits today was instantly dropped. Why was that?
I can still see those edits, and the posts are still there.
[image]

Comment: This is probably the same as [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142810/getting-two-reputation-points-for-a-suggested-edit-even-after-reaching-the-1000), where you're somewhat erroneously being awarded points for suggested edits past the 1000-reputation-from-suggested-edits limit, and then the system autocorrects after the fact.

Comment: oh, i didn't even know there was such a limit. I guess that makes sense though.

Comment: @TimStone but if that's true, then wasn't I supposed to get the copy editor badge for 500 edits?

Comment: And apparently i still get rep for new edits

Comment: `I3arnon had 617 edit suggestions approved, and 30 edit suggestions rejected` so don't know why you haven't got the badge.

Comment: Though [according to this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/445/145673) not all edits contribute to the badge so maybe you are still not quite there.

Comment: @MartinSmith I know, but i can't go there because i used all my votes today

Comment: I assume you are talking about [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149516/145673). I deleted it from my previous comment because despite the claim in the comments that "Copy Editor and Electorate" have been added to the display I don't see this myself.

Comment: Oh, I see, it depends on what queue you have open what badges you see. Can you go to this URL directly http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3732759 or does it block you?

Comment: I can, apparently, and it says i have 8 edits left. So i guess some edits just didn't count like you said. Thank you

Comment: Tag edits don't count for the badge, though you get +2 reputation for an approved suggested tag-edit.

Comment: @I3arnon when you go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation, what you see as the [X] in the last line, "earned [X] reputation from suggested edits"?

Comment: Yes.. A thousand. I also got the badge.