# Reputation mismatch on SO

Tags: bug, reputation

At /reputation it is 2614.  On my main page it is 2618.  Usually, something like this would be 2 edits that I had previously received +2 for were deleted, but I can't detect why I lost these 4 points according to the reputation page.  My account has been like this for at least 1 week I believe.  Can you please investigate the behavior of the automated reputation recalc?

[image]

And

[image]

Comment: Actually, I think I know what it is.  On Jan 14, I got + 4 for tag wiki and that does not appear on my reputation page.  Why do tag wiki points not appear?

Comment: For me, you have 2618 points.

Comment: Think I know what happened and if so it's a bug. You already have 1000 points from suggested edits, which is the maximum. The +4 you got from those edits (which do appear in [your profile reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/236247/demongolem?tab=reputation)) should be +0 or not be there at all. The audit page is correct, reputation calculation got a bug.

Comment: Worth to mention, it [used to work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142810/152859) by removing the +2 in the daily job making sure reputation is recalculated.

Comment: Is the bug fixed now?  I just lost 4 points within the last hour I think.