# Reputation not (or wrongly) recalculated after overriding suggested edit approval when 1000 reputation limit applies

Tags: bug, reputation, suggested-edits

You can only earn a maximum of [1000 reputation by suggesting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77508/295232); I reached that level [two years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/228959/glorfindel?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2017-06-24&page=2) on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Last week, one of my approved suggested edits was [overridden by the post owner](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2222244/revisions), causing my reputation to decrease from [3466](https://web.archive.org/web/20190919073357/https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1110490?UserId=228959) to [3464](http://web.archive.org/web/20190919073449/https://math.stackexchange.com/users/228959/glorfindel?tab=reputation). I would expect this to have no influence since one of the later suggested edits should now be allowed to contribute since I'm no longer over the limit. (Note that my reputation is now 3474 due to another recent answer upvote.)

When I look at my [reputation log](https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation), it (still?) says

```
earned 1000 reputation from suggested edits
```

which is *probably* wrong, I'd expect it to be 998 now. But when I count the edits in that log (the lines starting with [`16`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1115225)), <s>I</s> my browser counts only 494 entries. (Which could be right, if some of the posts I edited were deleted later. But in that case, I'd expect the latest suggested edits to give +2 as well in the reputation tab on the profile page.)

I hope this is enough information to properly analyze this bug. If I need to make a relevant suggested edit to a tag wiki for further testing, just let me know.

Comment: I asked a sinilair question years ago on MSO, status-by-design.

Comment: [This one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360393/4751173)

Comment: Yes @Glorfindel

Comment: Hmm, so the real issue here has nothing to do with the reversion. There seems to be something weird going on in detection of eligible votes. The *only* approved suggested edits you have on your account that haven't given you the +2 reputation are on tag wikis and excerpts (21 of them), some of which occurred before other regular-post suggested edits that have since been granted +2 because of the deletion of other posts. So... it seems like the recalc system is just ignoring votes on tag wikis and excerpts when trying to give the +2 back out, and you've run out of normal posts to give credit.

Comment: I'm glad to have found another edge case in the system :)