# Tag wiki edit titles don't show up in the reputation drop down

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-summary

See here:

[image: missing tag edit descriptions]

I added some tag wikis to Super User which show up as +2 on my drop down, but there's no text to indicate what I got the edit for. They're also missing from the reputation page of my profile:

[image: missing tag edit descriptions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we don't know the title "tag wiki" will now show up for these, if performance allows we'll look at pulling which tag it was for as well in these cases...the way it's stored currently isn't totally cheap in the scheme of things in the batch way we're pulling it (as opposed to one-at-a-time display it's optimized for).